# Size of the training data of GPT2-XL pre-trained model

Tags: pytorch, language-model, huggingface-transformers

In [huggingface transformer](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers), it is possible to use the pre-trained GPT2-XL language model. But I don't find, on which dataset it is trained? Is it the same trained model which OpenAI used for their [paper](https://cdn.openai.com/better-language-models/language_models_are_unsupervised_multitask_learners.pdf) (trained on 40GB dataset called `webtext`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPT2-XL model is the biggest of the four architectures detailed in the paper you linked (1542M parameters). It is trained on the same data as the other three, which is the WebText you're mentioning.

Comment: Are there any details on training setup (hyper parameters and training hardware), as well as total training time?

Answer (score 0):

The GPT2-XL model is the biggest of the four architectures detailed in the paper you linked (1542M parameters). It is trained on the same data as the other three, which is the WebText you're mentioning.

Size of 6GB